# The video identified by the parameter has disabled comments

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The video identified by the `videoId` parameter has disabled comments. [403]
Errors [
Message[The video identified by the `videoId` parameter has disabled comments.] Location[videoId - parameter] Reason[commentsDisabled] Domain[youtube.commentThread]
]

API:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list

How to get other video comments?

Comment: What are the parameters you are using for this endpoint?